# JavaScript variable not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a simple Chrome Extension.

At the top of the document, I have put `var maxLengthVar;`.

I have stored a number using the `chrome.storage` API. I am `get`ting the value using:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('maxLength', function (items) {
    maxLengthVar = items.maxLength;
    console.log(maxLengthVar);
});
```

The `console.log` displays the correct value (`2`). But when I try to use this variable, I get `undefined`:

```
console.log(maxLengthVar);
document.getElementById("textToChange").innerHTML = maxLengthVar;
```

Note: this code is **directly below** the first piece of code.

I expect to have the console log the number `2` and the div `textToChange`'s content to change to `2`, but, instead, I get `undefined` in the console and the div stays the same. Why is this?

From what I understand, I have a global variable because at the top of the document, I declared the variable, so what makes the `document.getElementById`... not read the variable?

Another thing is that even though the `console.log`'s I said above are in the same order in the document, they appear in the console reversed (ie. I get `undefined` first and then `2`.) I know because I added some text (`'text' + maxLengthVar`) to the `console.log`'s. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read up on `async` methods.

Basically the `get` method is an async method. While this method is executing the remainder of your script will execute printing out `undefined`

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('maxLength', function (items) {
    maxLengthVar = items.maxLength;
    console.log(maxLengthVar);
});

// <- at this point the async GET method may not have finished executing
//    but your code continues anyway

console.log(maxLengthVar);
document.getElementById("textToChange").innerHTML = maxLengthVar;
```

Your code can be re-written using callbacks

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('maxLength', function (items) {
    maxLengthVar = items.maxLength;
    document.getElementById("textToChange").innerHTML = maxLengthVar;
});
```

Comment: ok, not very clear on callbacks - a callback is a function with a parameter being another function? Please correct me if I'm wrong. Also, I don't understand the use of using these. Is their an answer on SO to explain these? Thanks. I think I should mark as accepted because you solved my problem, but if you could answer these other questions, I'd be grateful!